# Best way to chain together two SPO cmdlets

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, modern-experience, powershell-script, site-design

In the [Sharepoint Online Management Shell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/introduction-sharepoint-online-management-shell?view=sharepoint-ps) my goal is to call the cmdlet `Invoke-SPOSiteDesign` [(doc)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/invoke-spositedesign?view=sharepoint-ps) with one fixed Design (i.e. the `-Identity` parameter) onto all SPOSites on my tenant.

I can get all sites with `Get-SPOSite` [(doc)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-sposite?view=sharepoint-ps) but I don't know how to chain those two commands together.
Pseudo-Code wise, I want:

```
for every $url retrieved by Get-SPOSite:
    Invoke-SPOSiteDesign -Identity 0000-0000-0000 -WebUrl $url
```

Can you help me on how to express that best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
# Get all site collections
$siteCollections = Get-SPOSite

# loop through all site collections
foreach($siteCollection in $siteCollections) {
    Invoke-SPOSiteDesign -Identity 0000-0000-0000 -WebUrl $siteCollection.url
}
```